# How to specify that a value is bigger than its previous value with asp.net data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations, model-validation

How can I ensure that an entity is bigger than an entity before it, such as in my following example of refilling a car with fuel, or a tank with water:

```
    [Required()]
    [Range(0.00, 100000.00)]
    public double BeforeRefill { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Range(BeforeRefill , 100000.00)]
    public double AfterRefill { get; set; }
```

I want to achieve something like above, how ever it does not work in my code.

Is there a way in which I can create a custom Validation Attribute in which I perform such a check. Or some how implement my own validation so that when I call `ModelState.isvalid()` it will check?

Comment: Attribute arguments in .NET must be consts. It sounds like you need custom model validation instead. You can't use validation attributes for that, you will have to use a different approach.

Comment: the attribute argument is a const if you make it "BeforeRefill" (or slab an matching attribute on the beforerefill property like [FindPropertyById(1)] and then you can look for an property with the matching attribute. the value of BeforeRefill can be resolved in your isValid call

Answer (score 2):

just inherit from the validationattribute class. see also

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC

you can get the object you are checking from validationContext.ObjectInstance and then you can use reflection to find the other value.